# pdo select row by number

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying to change over to PDO, and I am missing something simple?

OLD WAY

```
$query="SELECT * FROM database"
$result=mysql_query($query);

$data=mysql_result($result, 2, "value");
```

This gets me a value from row 3, using PDO the only way I can figure is:

```
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
$row = $result->fetch();
$row = $result->fetch();
$row = $result->fetch();
$thisone = $row['value'];
```

This way seems silly and indirect, is there a better way to select a row by it's number? I need the whole database queried for other variables, so changing the database SELECT statement won't work.

Comment: Use `fetchAll` instead, then grab the contents of index 2 from the returned array.

Comment: @bfavaretto, post that as an answer (maybe with a bit more sample code?) not just a comment so it can be voted up.

Comment: @pjmorse I was lazy when I posted that comment. Added something slightly better as an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to get an array containing all rows. Then it's just a matter of grabbing the row you're looking for:

```
$rows = $result->fetchAll();
$third = $rows[2];
$value = $third['value'];
```

Comment: Cool, then just $value = $third['value'] Thanks.

Comment: Exactly. Added that to the answer for completeness.